# Freebase MQL - Any way to copy an element's value to a new element in lowercase?

Tags: javascript, freebase, mql

In the following basic MQL, is there a way to retrieve the film's name as a lowercase copy of itself? Maybe by passing a Javascript toLowerCase() or something to a variable copy?

```
[{
  'type':'/film/film',
  'limit':5,
  'name':null,
}]​
```

Maybe something like (pseudo code):

```
[{
  'type':'/film/film',
  'limit':5,
  'name':null,
  'lc_name':'name.val.toLowerCase()'
}]​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MQL doesn't have any transformation operators or functions.  Since you need to use a programming language to send and receive the MQL though, and all programming languages have library functions which can do this, you should be able to just use your programming language.

In Python, you'd use something like result[0].name.lower().  Java and other languages have similar facilities.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I'll just do it in my node.js script.